# Can I make multiple estimated tax payments to the IRS in a single quarter?

Tags: united-states, irs, estimated-taxes

I know I'm *required* to make *at least* one payment every quarter before a certain date, but can I make multiple, smaller payments? Will it cause me any trouble if I do?

The most I could find was:

> IRS Direct Pay won't accept more than two payments within a 24-hour period

which only applies to that particular form of payment, but does seem to allow for plenty more than one payment per quarter.

Comment: A few years ago when owing taxes on my 1040, I made more than one payment per quarter via Direct Pay.  That doesn't directly answer your question but seems to indicate that the answer is yes.

Comment: I doubt any tax authority would complain about getting *more* money. Are you asking about paying, say, two quarters’ worth of taxes in one quarter, or about spreading the single quarter’s worth of taxes over multiple payments?

Comment: You don't actually HAVE to make a payment every quarter, you just need to have the payments keep up with your income.  So for instance I might have no income in the 3rd quarter this year (after making payments on income I got the first two quarters), so I would have no need to make a payment.  (At least that's my understanding, and what I've actually done for the last couple of decades.)

Comment: @Lawrence I meant spreading what would normally be paid in one payment into multiple, smaller payments.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. I'm not a tax specialist but I send a monthly payment to the IRS for my business.

I've found it has a few benefits:

1. You write smaller checks vs. paying all at once
2. You can better understand your business's true profitability
3. You can make adjustments to your monthly payments if you expect a divergence from your sales estimates

Comment: "You can better understand your business's true profitability".  You could transfer that money each month to a "holding pen" savings account, and then from there to the IRS as required.  It would allow you to stay liquid longer, though might tempt you to spend it on a hot trade...